# If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has two derivatives such that $f(0) =0$ and $ f'(x) \leq f(x), \forall x,$ then $f\equiv 0 \ ?$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has two derivatives such that $f(0) =0$ and $ f'(x) \leq f(x), \forall x.$ Could anyone advise me how to prove/disprove that $f \equiv 0 \ ?$ Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use integrating factors like in differential equations here. Your assumption is
$$f(x) - f'(x) \geq 0$$
This is the same as
$$e^{-x} f(x) - e^{-x} f'(x) \geq 0$$
Which is the same as
$${d \over dx} (e^{-x} f(x))\leq 0$$
This shouldn't be too hard to analyze...

Comment: Do you have any ide, why in the OP's question the requirement of existence of second derivatives is given? In your solution this is not used.

Comment: no idea.. maybe the asker had a different method in mind

Comment: @Zarrax: So $f$ is indeed the zero function?

Comment: Based on your hints, I only gather that $f'(x) \leq 0$ and $ f(x) \leq 0, x \geq 0$ and $f(x) \geq 0, x \leq 0.$

Comment: $f(x)$ doesn't have to be identically zero... try writing a function satisfying the condition which is not identically zero, there are many.

Comment: Thank you. But how has it got to do with your solution?

Comment: Let $f(x)= 1-e^{x}....$

Comment: Yep, that works. Any function of the form $e^x h(x)$ with $h(x)$ decreasing and $h(0) = 0$ will also work.

Comment: @ zarrax, what about the function $f(x)=((x)_-)^2$? (it is $C^1$!). This function fulfils the assumption on $f$ since it is decreasing. It is zero on $[0,\infty)$. The product with $e^{-x}$ is also decreasing. To put it short: I think one only gets the claimed statement for $x\geq 0$

Answer (score 1):

The functions $f_k(x)=((x)_-)^{2k}$ $k\geq 2$ provide a counter example ($k\geq 2$ due to second differentiability, $(x)_-$ is the negative part). Note that $f_k'(x)\leq 0$ and $f_k(x)\geq 0$ for every $x$.

By the way, there are further examples like

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{1/x}&x<0\\0& x\geq 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: no comment so far?